# Accordion not showing in tabs? Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Having some trouble with something hoping someone may be able to help out.

Below is a link for tabs, and accordion (both work perfect separately)

**Tabs**
jsfiddle.net/31oftamq/6/

**Accordion**
jsfiddle.net/xLh6k5fm/2/

When I put the accordion in the content area for one of the tabs, the accordion does not appear whatsoever when I run it.

Anyone know what the issue could be? Help will be much appreciated.

Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but would using a child selector instead of a descendant selector for the tabs-stage help?`$('.tabs-stage > div').hide();`

Comment: Please show the fiddle where you tried to put the two together so we can troubleshoot it.

Comment: I stuck it under the warranty tab: https://jsfiddle.net/3ypxecrf/

Comment: Thanks so much! It works perfect :) One last question if you can help me with it...when you click a question on the accordion, the answer shows. However, I would like to be able to click the question again to hide the content. Currently, if you click a question and repeat click it, it won't hide the content. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you hide it with this:

```
$('.tabs-stage div').hide();
```

Change it to:

```
$('.tabs-stage div[id^=tab]').hide();
```

Check full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/31oftamq/9/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! This works great. Copying and pasting my comment from above with one last issue if you can assist me with it: "when you click a question on the accordion, the answer shows. However, I would like to be able to click the question again to hide the content. Currently, if you click a question and repeat click it, it won't hide the content."

Comment: Hi jakob. Thanks for the quick response and help! On it's own, it works great, but when it is in the accordion, it will open and then close on its own. So it's a bit buggy when it is in the accordion. Any thoughts?

Comment: Works perfect! My mistake. Thanks so much jakob.